# slow search in a php array

Tags: php, arrays

i have a n array of 150 element and each element has 10 elements

and this is a sample of the array
[image]

i use this function to get elements by the sub elements element

```
public static function search_array_kv($array, $key, $value)
{
    $results = array();

    if (is_array($array)) {
        if (isset($array[$key]) && $array[$key] == $value) {
            $results[] = $array;
        }

        foreach ($array as $subarray) {
            $results = array_merge($results, self::search_array_kv($subarray, $key, $value));
        }
    }

    return $results;
}
```

i use it as a follow (just example)

```
search_array_kv($cats,'parent',5);
```

according xdubug its called 48000 time and here is the problem

how can i fix it? is there any way instead of trying to get this called number lower

Comment: what would be an accepted input and an accepted output?

Comment: 2 years later... please complete this question by including your expected output from your sample input.  There may or may not be benefit to you for this, but it may help future readers, it may help to close future duplicate questions, your question may receive more upvotes, and it shows good role modeling to other users who are just learning how to post a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using array_filter() should be much faster. Could be done like this:

```
$searchKey = 'parent';
$searchValue = 5;

array_filter(
    $cats,
    function($value, $key) use($searchKey, $searchValue) {
        return (
            is_array($value) && // only look at arrays
            isset($value[$searchKey]) && // key $searchKey should exist
            $value[$searchKey] == $searchValue // value matches $searchValue
        );
    },
    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH
);
```

A detailed documentation including examples can be found at http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Answer (score 2):

I can see two solutions to your problem. Either you write more efficient PHP, or you request your data source with more precision.

For the first solution I would never made the function recursive inside a for each loop. Here is an example of a linear complexity function applied to your need:

```
/**
 * Search for all elements, in an array, that match a key value pair.
 * @param array $array The array to search for the elements.
 * @param mixed $key The key of the associative array to match the value.
 * @param mixed $value The value to be searched for.
 */
function search_array_kv ( $array, $key, $value )
{
    $results = array();

    if ( !is_array( $array ) ) return;
    foreach ( $array as $array_value )
    {
        if ( !is_array( $array_value ) ) continue;
        foreach ( $array_value as $subarray )
        {
            if ( !isset( $subarray[ $key ] ) ) continue;
            if ( $subarray[ $key ] === $value ) $results[] = $subarray;
        }
    }

    return $results;
}
```

The second solution is to make the query to your data source as precise as it can be. If it's a SQL database you can easily achieve this goal.

Bonus, here is a code to test my function and a possible result.

```
$array = array();

for ( $i = 0; $i < 150; $i++ )
{
    $array[ $i ] = array();
    for ( $j = 0; $j < 10; $j++ )
    {
        $array[ $i ][ $j ] = array(
            'id' => rand( 0, 499 ),
            'parent' => rand( 0, 499 )
        );
    }
}

var_dump( search_array_kv( $array, 'parent', 123 ) );
```

[image: A possible output of the function shown by the var_dump instruction in the test code.]

Answer (score 1):

I would try:

1. to use `array_key_exists()` instead of `isset()` (the latter is somewhat more complex than just checking if the key exists);
2. avoid using `array_merge()` in a loop, and instead accumulate arrays as items in another array, and then merge them at once with `call_user_func_array('array_merge', $arrayOfArrays)`;
3. probably use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-column.php) to get an array of values for the exact key, then check if it contains the value you are interested in and get its index with `array_search()`.